# PySpark Writing DataFrame Partitions to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've been trying to partition and write a spark dataframe to S3 and I get an error.

```
df.write.partitionBy("year","month").mode("append")\
    .parquet('s3a://bucket_name/test_folder/')
```

Error message is:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: xxxxxx, 
AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, 
AWS Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

However, when I simply write without partitioning **it does work**.

```
df.write.mode("append").parquet('s3a://bucket_name/test_folder/')
```

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this problem by upgrading from `aws-java-sdk:1.7.4` to `aws-java-sdk:1.11.199` and `hadoop-aws:2.7.7` to `hadoop-aws:3.0.0` in my spark-submit.

I set this in my python file using:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.199,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.0.0 pyspark-shell
```

But you can also provide them as arguments to spark-submit directly.

I had to rebuild Spark providing my own version of Hadoop 3.0.0 to avoid dependency conflicts.

You can read some of my speculation as to the root cause here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51917228/10239681